# What's the protocol for calling Raku code from C code?

Tags: raku

**2023 update** The last person to edit this Q deleted the critically important "LATEST LATEST UPDATE" part that @zentrunix had added near the top. I'm reinstating it.

## LATEST LATEST UPDATE

Please see my answer below.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer and understand this question.

## Original question

Say I have my event-driven TCP communications library in C.

From my Raku application, I can call a function in the C library using NativeCall.

```
my $server = create-server("127.0.0.1", 4000);
```

Now, from my callback in C (`say onAccept`) I want to call out to a Raku function in my application (say `on-accept(connection)` where `connection` will be a pointer to a C struct).

So, how can I do that: call my Raku function `on-accept` from my C function `onAccept` ?

ps. I tried posting using a simple title "How to call Raku code from C code", but for whatever reason stackoverflow.com wouldn't let me do it. Because of that I concocted this fancy title.

I was creating a 32-bit DLL.
We have to explicitly tell CMake to configure a 64-bit build.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..
```

Anyway, now that the code runs, it's not really what I asked for, because the callback is still in C.

It seems that what I asked for it's not really possible.

I tried to use the approach suggested by Haakon, though I'm afraid I don't understand how it would work.

I'm in Windows, and unfortunately, Raku can't find my dlls, even if I put them in C:\Windows\System32. It finds "msvcrt" (C runtime), but not my dlls.

The dll code (Visual Studio 2015).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)

typedef int (*proto)(const char*);

proto raku_callback;

extern EXPORTED void set_callback(proto);
extern EXPORTED void foo(void);

void set_callback(proto arg)
{
  printf("In set_callback()..\n");
  raku_callback = arg;
}

void foo(void)
{
  printf("In foo()..\n");
  int res = raku_callback("hello");
  printf("Raku return value: %d\n", res);
}
```

Cmake code for the

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 3.1)
add_library (my_c_dll SHARED my_c_dll.c)
```

Raku code.

```
use v6.d;

use NativeCall;

sub set_callback(&callback (Str --> int32))
  is native("./my_c_dll"){ * }

sub foo()
  is native("./my_c_dll"){ * }

sub callback(Str $str --> Int) {
  say "Raku callback.. got string: {$str} from C";
  return 32;
}

## sub _getch() returns int32 is native("msvcrt") {*};
## print "-> ";
## say "got ", _getch();

set_callback(&callback);
# foo();
```

When I run

```
$ raku test-dll.raku
Cannot locate native library '(null)': error 0xc1
  in method setup at D:\tools\raku\share\perl6\core\sources
    \947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 298
  in block set_callback at D:\tools\raku\share\perl6\core\sources
     \947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 594
  in block <unit> at test-dll.raku line 21
```

Raku version.

```
$ raku -v
This is Rakudo version 2020.05.1 built on MoarVM version 2020.05
implementing Raku 6.d.
```

Comment: I'm not frustrated, I'm enlightened :) ... as to the error in loading the dll, it was my fault

Comment: for a little more context, in Lua, C code *can* call Lua code,so maybe it would also be possible to do something like that in Raku ... so, that's why I posted this question

Comment: According to Wikipedia, for Lua, "...the interpreter of compiled bytecode is written in ANSI C, and Lua has a relatively simple C API to embed it into applications." So if the question you're posting is closer to the title @raiph suggests (i.e. interoperability), it's natural to assume that Lua/C interoperability will be easier than Raku/C interoperability.

Comment: @jubilatious1 I made a simple question, "Is it possible to call Raku from C ?", and that's it ... it seems it's not possible, and that's ok by me, I'm not frustrated, nor angry, it was simply something that I wanted to know

Comment: .@jubilatious1 I see I never replied to your comment that "it's natural to assume that Lua/C interoperability will be easier than Raku/C interoperability." The accepted answer by Håkon Hægland shows how Raku interop is both easier and safer. Using Lua you have to write C code that embeds Lua (`luaL_newstate`, `luaL_openlibs`, etc), explicitly manually marshal arguments (`luaL_loadstring` etc), and do explicit manual stack management (`lua_pop` etc). It's not just `lua_pcall`.

Comment: I see I haven't left a reply to .@zentrunix's last comment which preceded us clearing up the confusion after they first asked their question. The answer to the simple question "Is it possible to call Raku from C?" is **YES**. Not only that, but it's easier and safer than calling Lua from C. This is why .@zentrunix accepted Håkon Hægland's answer, and why the conclusion of .@zentrunix's own answer was "What amazes me is that the Raku signature for my_raku_function maps cleanly to the C signature ... isn't Raku wonderful ?".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another approach could be to save a callback statically in the C library, for example (`libmylib.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int (*raku_callback)(char *arg);

void set_callback(int (*callback)(char * arg)) {
    printf("In set_callback()..\n");
    raku_callback = callback;
}

void foo() {
    printf("In foo()..\n");
    int res = raku_callback("hello");
    printf("Raku return value: %d\n", res);
}
```

Then from Raku:

```
use v6;
use NativeCall;

sub set_callback(&callback (Str --> int32)) is native('./libmylib.so') { * }
sub foo() is native('./libmylib.so') { * }

sub callback(Str $str --> Int) {
    say "Raku callback.. got string: {$str} from C";
    return 32;
}

set_callback(&callback);
foo();
```

**Output**:

```
In set_callback()..
In foo()..
Raku callback.. got string: hello from C
Raku return value: 32
```

Comment: although it's not the answer I was hoping for, it's a nice answer, because it shows how easy it is to use native calls (to C) in Raku

Comment: When .@zentrunix wrote their comment they had not realized this answer in fact *was* what they were hoping for, because it not only shows how to call C code from Raku code, but also how to call Raku code from C code. (Not to mention that it's easier and safer than the equivalents back and forth between C and Lua.)

Answer (score 6):

[Raku](https://raku.org) is a compiled language; depending on the implementation you've got, it will be compiled to [MoarVM](https://www.moarvm.org/), JVM or Javascript. Through compilation, Raku code becomes bytecode in the corresponding virtual machine. So it's never, actually, binary code.

However, Raku code seems to be cleverly organized in a way that an object is actually a pointer to a C endpoint, as proved by [Haakon Hagland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%c3%a5kon-h%c3%a6gland) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289340/891440).

WRT to your latest problem, please bear in mind that what you are calling is not a path, but a name that is converted to a navive shared library name and also uses [local library path conventions](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#Library_paths_and_names) to look for them (it's `PATH' on Windows). So if it's not finding it, add local path to it of simply copy the DLL to one of the searched directories.

Comment: In the case I've used in my question the connections would also be handled by C code, but yes, I think you're right, callbacks (especially asynchronous callbacks generated by multi-threaded applications) would have to be handle by C code ... the interaction between Raku code and C code would have to serialized (as in not muliti-threaded), but I think there's no other way to do that (in fact, I believe that's how node.js works) ... thanks for your input

Comment: @raiph I do know the "actors" concept, although I have zero experince with it; now, right after I wrote the comment above I realized that, with some care, maybe Raku code **can** interact with C code in a non-serialized way: say, 2 "start" blocks in Raku, each calling a different C function which wait for events delivered by other parts of the C code; as for C calling Raku functions directly, I don't know if there's an easy way of doing that like (as I said above) Lua allows it: see [here](https://lucasklassmann.com/blog/2019-02-02-how-to-embeddeding-lua-in-c/) the function `lua_pcall`

Comment: @raiph please note that I'm not an expert neither in Raku nor in Lua :)

Comment: @raiph no I don't. I can't delete the answer, though. I'll see.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, my apologies to @Håkon and @raiph.
Sorry for being so obtuse. :)

Håkon's answer does indeed answer my question, although for whatever reason I have failed to see that until now.

Now the code I played with in order to understand Håkon's solution.

---

```
// my_c_dll.c
// be sure to create a 64-bit dll

#include <stdio.h>

#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)

typedef int (*proto)(const char*);

proto raku_function;

extern EXPORTED void install_raku_function(proto);
extern EXPORTED void start_c_processing(void);

void install_raku_function(proto arg)
{
  printf("installing raku function\n");
  raku_function = arg;
}

void start_c_processing(void)
{
  printf("* ----> starting C processing..\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    printf("* %d calling raku function\n", i);
    int res = raku_function("hello");
    printf("* %d raku function returned: %d\n", i, res);
    Sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

---

```
# test-dll.raku

use v6.d;

use NativeCall;

sub install_raku_function(&raku_function (Str --> int32))
  is native("./my_c_dll.dll") { * }

sub start_c_processing()
  is native("./my_c_dll.dll") { * }

sub my_raku_function(Str $str --> Int)
{
  say "@ raku function called from C with parameter [{$str}]";
  return 32;
}

install_raku_function &my_raku_function;

start { start_c_processing; }

for ^1000 -> $i
{
  say "# $i idling in raku";
  sleep 1;
}
```

---

```
$ raku test-dll.raku                   
installing raku function               
# 0 idling in raku                     
* ----> starting C processing..        
* 0 calling raku function              
@ 0 raku function called from C with parameter [hello]
* 0 raku function returned: 32         
# 1 idling in raku                     
* 1 calling raku function              
@ 1 raku function called from C with parameter [hello]
* 1 raku function returned: 32         
# 2 idling in raku                     
* 2 calling raku function              
@ 2 raku function called from C with parameter [hello]
* 2 raku function returned: 32         
# 3 idling in raku                     
* 3 calling raku function              
@ 3 raku function called from C with parameter [hello]
* 3 raku function returned: 32         
# 4 idling in raku                     
* 4 calling raku function              
@ 4 raku function called from C with parameter [hello]
* 4 raku function returned: 32         
# 5 idling in raku                     
* 5 calling raku function              
@ 5 raku function called from C with parameter [hello]
* 5 raku function returned: 32         
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?           
^C
```

What amazes me is that the Raku signature for `my_raku_function` maps cleanly to the C signature ... isn't Raku wonderful ? :)

Comment: It really is :-)

Comment: Cool that you made it work on Windows, I am trying on Windows now, but I get "Cannot locate native library '(null)': error 0xc1" when I run the script. How did you compile the shared library? I compiled with Visual Studio 2019 from the developer command prompt: `cl.exe /c my_c_dll.c` and then `link /DLL /OUT:my_c_dll.dll my_c_dll.obj`

Comment: @HåkonHægland you're creating a 32-bit dll ... 0xc1 ---> 193 [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) ... raku wants a 64-bit dll ... I've used cmake to create the solution, so I had to tell cmake to create a 64-bit solution ... in your case, you have to open a 64-bit developer prompt ... I have VS2017, it has 5 "developer prompts" in the start menu ... one of them will be the 64-bit shell for visual studio for sure

Comment: @zentrunix Interesting! Yes there are many prompts in the start menu, I now tried  the one called *"x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019"*, but it gives the same error here too..

Comment: @zentrunix My bad, I needed to use the  *"x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019"* (not the x86 of course) It now works! I posted a summary [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66510786/2173773) for reference