# How to compile a shared library on Windows such that it can be used with NativeCall in raku?

Tags: windows, dll, raku

I am trying to compile a DLL library on Windows that can be used with [NativeCall](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall) in Raku. Here is a minimal C code (`my_c_dll.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)
extern __declspec(dllexport) void foo();

void foo()
{
  printf("Hello from C\n");
}
```

I am on Windows 10 and have installed [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019). To compile the DLL I open a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" and run:

```
> cl.exe /c my_c_dll.c
> link /DLL /OUT:my_c_dll.dll my_c_dll.obj
```

This creates a DLL `my_c_dll.dll`, then I try to use this from Raku (`test-dll.raku`):

```
use v6.d;
use NativeCall;
sub foo() is native("./my_c_dll.dll"){ * }
foo();
```

but when I run this (I have installed Rakudo version 2020.05.1) I get:

```
> raku test-dll.raku
Cannot locate native library '(null)': error 0xc1
  in method setup at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\core\sources\947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 298
  in block foo at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\core\sources\947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 594
  in block <unit> at test-dll.raku line 9
```

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Cannot locate native library '(null)': error 0xc1

The error code `0xc1` is a [Windows system error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) :

```
ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT
193 (0xC1)
%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

By inspecting the header of the DLL using [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160)

```
> dumpbin /headers my_c_dll.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.26.28806.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file my_c_dll.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               4 number of sections
        6043A8CB time date stamp Sat Mar  6 17:07:39 2021
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
            2102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine
                   DLL
```

I observe that it says `machine (x86)` and `32 bit word machine`, so I suspect the DLL is a 32-bit DLL. However, I am on a 64 bit machine:

```
> PowerShell -Command "systeminfo | perl -nE 'say if /System Type/'"
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

It turns out that the `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019` installed some more developer prompts in addition to the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019", namely:

- x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019
- x64_x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019
- x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019
- x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019

By opening a "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" and recompiling the DLL here, I now get:

```
> dumpbin /headers my_c_dll.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.26.28806.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file my_c_dll.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               6 number of sections
        6043AAA2 time date stamp Sat Mar  6 17:15:30 2021
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

Notice that the output now says `machine (x64)` and `Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses`, and this also seems to fix the problem:

```
> raku test-dll.raku
Hello from C
```