# Calling C function from Raku that was compiled in C++ on Windows, Why is it not working?

Tags: windows, dll, raku

I have this code in 64bit dll on Windows

```
#define TEMPLATENEST_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern  "C"  TEMPLATENEST_API  void templatenest_init(void** object);

 void templatenest_init(void** object)
{
    //TemmplNest
    *object =(void*) new TemplateNestClass();

}
```

In raku,

```
sub templatenest_init(Pointer is rw) is native(dl) { * }


 my Pointer  $class_pointer;

 templatenest_init($class_pointer);
 templatenest_init($class_pointer)
```

However, after this line, $class_pointer was 0.
Somehow the value of a the class pointer does not arrive in Raku.
I checked in a Debugger that *object was set to non zero value.

Signature of the exported function
2    1 00025621 templatenest_init = @ILT+5660(templatenest_init)

Minimal example:
Use Microsoft VIsual studio 2019 compile as dll library 64 bit

raku:

```
use v6;
use Data::Dump;
use NativeCall; 

#constant dl = 'D:\m\cpp\TemplateNest\template-nest-rakudl\TemplateNestDll.dll';

constant dl = 'D:\m\cpp\TemplateNest\x64\Debug\DllMinitest.dll';



sub get_dll_name()
{
     if $*VM.osname eq 'linux' {
        return 'templatenest';
     }
     else
{
      return dl;
}

}
sub templatenest_init(Pointer is rw) is native(get_dll_name) { * }

my Pointer $class_pointer;

  templatenest_init($class_pointer);
   say "{$class_pointer.Int}";

# it prints 0.

export.cpp:
#define TEMPLATENEST_API __declspec(dllexport)

class TemplateNestClass {



};

extern  "C"  TEMPLATENEST_API  void templatenest_init(void** object);

void templatenest_init(void** object)
{
    //TemmplNest
    *object = (void*) new TemplateNestClass();

}



dllmain:
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: How do you compile the DLL? Can you create a minimal compilable C++ project that generates a dll and still produces the issue, for example like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66510786/2173773) question. Then we can try reproduce. See also [mcve] for more information

Comment: It does not seem to work under Linux either...

Comment: Minimal example fails.

Comment: Have you read and tested per [C++ support](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#C++_support)?

Comment: AIUI, it's still true that, as per an SO which ended up with "This works for me. I just stopped using `Pointer` and ... 'is rw' works fine", NativeCall has "some rough edges that at times necessitate a bit of creativity; this might be one of those cases." There are 7 [Raku SOs with `Pointer` and `is rw` in their code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+-user%3A9713817+code%3A%22Pointer%22+code%3A%22rw%22), including the one I quoted. Maybe one of them leads toward getting a working program?

Answer (score 6):

A work around seems to work.

```
extern  "C"  TEMPLATENEST_API  void templatenest_init(__int64 * object);

sub templatenest_init(int64 is rw ) is native(get_dll_name) { * }

my int64 $class_pointer;

templatenest_init($class_pointer);
```

Actual answer:
The pointer needs to be initialised like this:
my Pointer $class_pointer = Pointer.new();

All Pointer stuff needs to be new-ed.
Another example:
my Pointer[Str] $html = Pointer[Str].new();

Comment: What doc and/or Raku(do) updates would you suggest we consider in reaction to this SO? In that vein I have two simpler questions: "A work around seems to work" How did you figure that out? Was it the SO I mentioned? "Actual answer" Again, how did you figure that out?

Comment: Reading the documentation.. and testing the solution... There was a similar example.  I read this https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall... read between the lines... there was an example with CArray[Str].new.... by the way, "Basic_use_of_pointer" should contain an example of that.. it does not.... it should be mentioned...  that new pointer needs to be constructed.. by the way, there is example of that...    I just noticed couple of minutes ago... >>>(inet_ntop(AF_INET, Pointer.new(nativecast(Pointer,self)+4),
            $buf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN)<<< though it looks convoluted

Comment: So I assumed it must work similarly to CArray[Str]

Comment: That's *excellent* info *and* guidance. Thank you! One last question: "So I assumed it must work similarly to CArray[Str]" Are you now confident your MREs/answer are indeed *fully* working?

Comment: Yes, tested on two platforms.

Comment: Excellent. I searched and there are (were) [7 open doc issues matching `NativeCall`](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+nativecall). I don't think any covered what you're taking about, and anyway, you're suggesting what seems to me like small useful doc clarifications, so I've filed [a new doc issue](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/4025) about this.

Comment: If you have a github account, please consider spending a few minutes directly editing the doc's `NativeCall` page by clicking [here](https://github.com/Raku/doc/edit/master/doc//Language/nativecall.pod6), making changes, previewing them, selecting the "Create a new branch for this commit" radio button at the bottom, and clicking the "Propose changes" button. Thanks!